# getting a collection back from a form in grails

Tags: forms, grails, checkbox, gsp

I have an album view where a user can check which photos to delete. I am currently doing this:

```
<g:form action="delete">
    <g:each in="${pictures}">

        <div id="images2">
            <img id="images2" src="${it.urlThumb}" alt="no Picture"/><br>
            <g:checkBox name="myCheckbox"/>
        </div>

    </g:each>
    <g:submitButton name="Submit"/>
</g:form>
```

The problem is this creates the form dynamically so each of the names are the same for the check boxes. I ideally want a collection returned to the controller that has each of the checked images.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `<g:checkBox>` you need to specify a value. Each checkbox will be created with the same name but a different value. When the form is submitted with different checkboxes checked, you will get a list in the controller.

View:

```
<g:each in="${pictures}">
    <div id="images2">
        <img id="images2" src="${it.urlThumb}" alt="no Picture"/><br>
        <g:checkBox name="myCheckbox" value="it.id"/>
    </div>
</g:each>
```

Controller:

```
def checked = params.list('myCheckbox')
```

Comment: hi thanks for this it works fine, the only issue i have is that all the check boxed are not ticked my default

Comment: That is a separate question